# Launching PS Sessions

Tags: powershell

In my development environment I always have three PS sessions running, such as Whales-Names, Docker and Gulp Watchers. I would like to have a single script that can I run that would automatically launch these these sessions for me and do the commands within each session that I need. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use the profile-file with the commands you need. If you use ISE run `psEdit $profile`. Otherwise see [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1]

Comment: Are we talking abour remote sessions? Or just three separate instances of `powershell.exe` you want to launch at the same time on your local dev machine?

Comment: Just locally on my machine. Launch the sessions and then pass commands to them.

Comment: Add them to your profile so that launch with each session or create a single function to launch them all.

Comment: Can you direct me to an example of a function that would do that?

Comment: Disregard. I think I found a way to do what I need. Thanks for the response though.